# error handling for nextjs typesense instant-search-hooks app

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js, react-instantsearch, typesense

Currently I'm trying to setup a nextjs app with firebase as backend. Because firebase cant handle a fulltext search, I want to use typesense. They provide a really nice documentation how to set it up: https://typesense.org/docs/guide/firebase-full-text-search.html

For typesene I already set up docker containers for all my 3 environment (the docker [typesense](https://typesense.org/) provides). To request information back from the docker I use the `typesense-instantsearch-adapter`- npm Package. In the app I have different user roles, so not everyone can see all indexed data - therefore I use a scoped search which is possible through the apiKey I generate when the users logs in ([scoped api key](https://typesense.org/docs/0.23.0/api/api-keys.html#generate-scoped-search-key)). The apiKey therefore is variable depending on the user and the user role. My current setup works fine and also the search is already working.

The only problem I have is, that I cannot catch the errors the `<InstantSearch>`-Component is throwing. For example if the docker is offline or if the generated apiKey is not valid.

I tried multiple solutions, but could not find a proper solution:

- Error boundary around the component ([react docu](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html))
- Error boundary npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary)
- Try/catch block around the component

I found a codesandbox that has a quit similar setup. The sandbox is using algolia instead of typesense, but the error that pops up is the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/fib6jm?file=/App.tsx:1043-1056

1. Go to App.tsx
2. line 38
3. remove string
4. `Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])` pops up

How can I catch / access this error to reroute or show an error screen?